# My js react app is running differently once I run 'npm run build' and try to view the deployed application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can launch the application.  And most of the app is working as intended.  But for some reason, the core file isn't running as intended.  Any pointers as to why my app would function differently in the deployed version, opposed to the npm start version?

More specifically, I created an app that runs chess that I'm building from scratch.  And the chess.js file is becoming wonky when trying to run the deployed version.

I can post specific snippets if anyone has an idea where to look.  But you can see the whole application here: https://github.com/StephenHubbard/MountainChess

Server file here: https://github.com/StephenHubbard/MountainChess/blob/Stephen/server/server.js

Comment: What do you mean by wonky? Can you explain the differences you see?

Comment: Where and how are you deploying this code? From an initial glance, it appears to be a full client/server application using websockets, and the server code is assumed to be running on port 7777 at the same host, there are a lot of potential things that could go wrong there so we need a lot more detail about your server setup.

Comment: You can actually view the "wonky" differences here on my current hosted version. https://www.mountain-chess.com/#/chess

Comment: Robin, you're correct in all of the above.  I'm not sure what else to share about my server set up past the file link I shared above.  Anything specific you might want to know?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, I've never deployed a websockets application but I could imagine difficulties, particularly if you needed to deploy the server code at a specific port. But that was assuming it was the websockets that were giving you difficulties, having viewed your link it appears the issue you're talking about is purely a front-end one of layout.

Comment: I do think you're on the right track fwiw.  I have a feeling my sockets not correctly functioning when deployed might be the culprit.  Thanks for your help.